# Print fields alignment misaligned on report

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, pascal

I have the following PrintValue code that prints a line to the report (tbasedxreportlink).  It prints two fields on one line in the header, the caption and m.  The problem is that m is never aligned straight for multiple lines.  It always prints all over the place.

How do I get it to align to the right or even print decimal aligned.

Printed Data

```
Caption One    4,685.33
Caption 2       4.99
Caption three    74,586.88
Caption 4     58.66
```

Code

```
procedure PrintValue(Caption, Value: string);
var
  m: string;
  s: string;
begin
  m := FormatFloat(',0.00 ;(,0.00);0.00 ', StrToFloat(Value));
  s := Format('%-24s %15s', [Caption, m]);
  AReportLink.PrinterPage.PageHeader.LeftTitle.Add(s);
end;
```

The font used on the report is Segoe UI if it matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no easy way to format the strings to get the desired effect.  The main reason for that is the simplicity of using the LeftTitle, CenterTitle or RightTitle 'boxes' - they only allow simple string text to be inserted.  Nothing fancy allowed not to mention the True Type Font issue.

In order to solve the problem I added a tPanel to the screen and dropped the all screen fields I needed to show up on the grid print to it.  I added a tdxCustomContainerReportLink to link to that panel.  I then used a tdxCompositionReportLink to print both the grid and the tdxCustomContainerReportLink (panel) as individual items when the print button was pressed by overwriting the current link code:

```
procedure TFrmViewAcct.dxBarBtnPrintClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dxCmpntPrtrDetail.CurrentLink := dxCmpntPrtrDetailLink2;
  inherited;
end;
```

Thus it prints the grid info then prints what ever is on the panel.  Problem solved and you can see how this solution can be flexible.

Yes I could have easily changed to a True Type font but that is an ugly workaround as far as I am concerned especially where standardized fonts need to be observed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using monospace (fixed-width) font, for example, Courier New or Lucida Console